# Execute the python scripts file within Matplotlib using the Jupyter notebook, but it always do't show figures. why?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

**Question:** I have a trouble when executing the python script file **myplot.py** using **!python3** in Jupyter notebook.

***i.e.:*** **!python3 myplot.py**

**The myplot.py code flowing:**

```
import matplotlib

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)

plt.plot(x, np.sin(x))
plt.plot(x, np.cos(x))

plt.show()
```

But it always don't show the figure. It show this **"Figure(640x480)"**. I need your help to resolve this trouble.

Comment: You need to initialize the jupyter backend:  Either `%matplotlib notebook` or `%matplotlib inline`.

Comment: I have added the  the %matplotlib notebook or %matplotlib inline, but also don't resloved this  problem.

Comment: OK, well you can't send the graphics from a shell command (`!python3 myplot.py`) to the notebook by any way that I know.  Even `run myplot.py` uses the non-graphical backend.  You can save the file and then display in the notebook

Comment: Thanks Jody Klymak!!